# html creating a dashboard for mobile

Tags: html

I have to create the following html, tried to use a div for the "last 24 hours" and "last month" and other divs with float left for other stuff, but it turned out all messed up.
please help me, what structure should use? table? divs? thks

[image]

Comment: I recommend using divs for layout and table for tabular / matrix stuff ... so I'd use divs here

Comment: You can use both table structure and div structure. I would recommend divs ... just because we are in 2012.

Comment: This isn't tabular data, so you should use divs

Comment: what u have done in css/html

Comment: hum everyone is saying to use divs, probably the best solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This begs to be a grid. I'd use `div`s with some ready made grid, like the one from [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem).

So for example it could look like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">LAST 24 HOURS</div>
    <div class="span6">LAST MONTH</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">283</div>
    <div class="span6">put a nested grid here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span3">Facebook<div class="value">10%</div></div>
    <div class="span3">Twitter<div class="value">9%</div></div>
    <div class="span3">Foursquare<div class="value">7%</div></div>
    <div class="span3">Others<div class="value">5%</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then add some css classes and use that to float, change font sizes, colors, etc.

Comment: hum this code with the classes for grids in jquery mobile are great!!